# Network calls are taking around 6-7 times more time on Kotlin Multiplatform mobile compared to native when integrating in Xcode for iOS

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Generated a framework for a demo project / POC to be integrated in Xcode, but when comparing the network calls I found a weird 6-7 times more time taken for network calls done through KMM, compared to the same calls when done in native swift.

I tried search a lot online but couldn't find any resource / use case who could have faced a similar issue with KMM in iOS.

Comment: Where from have you took this demo project? My default KMM plugin creates a project with no networking.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov this demo project was made by some other team in my company, it was made by some guys form android platform who had experience in Kotlin, those guys added some public methods which makes network requests in order to fetch the required models. But these requests are taking more time in when called through this demo framework vs the native calls

Comment: I was able to reproduce it and [reported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-3341), give it a vote using thumb icon.

Comment: Sure will do @PhilipDukhov